# Dictionary value compare and reassign

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to solve a itinerary problem, travel schedule.

Here is my existing code:

```
import array as arr

class Solution():
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def printItenary(self,d):
        reverse_d = dict()
        for i in d:
            if i and d[i]:
                reverse_d[d[i]] = i
            else:
                print("Invalid Input")
                return
        for i in reverse_d:
            if reverse_d[i] not in reverse_d:
                starting_pt = reverse_d[i]
                break;
        while(starting_pt in d):
            print(starting_pt,"->",d[starting_pt],end=", ")
            starting_pt = d[starting_pt]
 
 
if __name__=="__main__":
    d = dict()
    d["Chennai"] = "Banglore"
    d["Bombay"] = "Delhi"
    d["Goa"] = "Chennai"
    d["Delhi"] = "Goa"
    obj = Solution()
    obj.printItenary(d)
```

The problem is if I add another line,

```
d["Chennai"] = "Delhi"
```

then there are multiple values for a single item, so I want to give a condition, if multiple inputs are given, then I will give priority based on lexicographical order, except it is not the value is in a dead end (if it is the last stop).

So my problem is, how to compare the dictionary data and update the value based on those condition

Answer (score 0):

For determining lexicographical order you could use the `ord()` function; ord('b') > ord('a') == True

```
if d["Chennai"]:
    if ord(new_value[0]) > ord(d["Chennai"][0]):
        d["Chennai"] = new_value
else:
    d["Chennai"] = new_value
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you handle the edge case of the key not being present. If you want it case insensitive, then do `str.lower()` as well in the comparison.

```py
new_val = ...
val = d.get('Chennai')
val = min(val, new_val) if val else new_val
d['Chennai'] = val
```